# Trying to move the body tag using CSS in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, positioning, absolute

So I need to move the body tag up and down on the page using CSS so I've set it's position to absolute and set the css property 'top' to a value to move it up and down. This works fine in all browsers except IE where it wont budge and just stays in the original position (top:0). Any help will be really appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

instead of moving the body, add a wrapper div including eveything inside the body and move that

Answer (score 1):

Just add some margin to the body tag so you can move it around, e.g.

```
body {
   margin:20px 30px 40px 50px;
}
```

That seems a bit unnecessary though, you can just wrap everything in a container class and just move that, as another posted replied.